# What is the result of using this CSS?

Tags: html, css

I often see this code on some sites:

```
body:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -31700px;
}
```

What is the result of using this CSS?

Comment: http://www.search-this.com/2009/10/09/css-a-sticky-subject/

Comment: A really good write-up of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this Website, it's an opera fix http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html , on this site, it's used for a sticky footer.
Sticky footer means it always sticks to the bottom of any window, also when there is not enough content to fill the screen.

> **The CSS Code**
>   Below is the CSS code that makes your sticky footers actually stick to the bottom.

```
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f3Uvs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Used to add cosmetic content to an element, by using the content property. This element is inline by default. The ::before notation was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a discrimination between [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-classes) and [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements). Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Opera Browser grab the bottom of the window and move it up and then down to see that it's not working as expected. This has always been operas main problem.

So in that case `body:before { }` used.